# Special input stream that will read only multiple of size array

Tags: java, windows, inputstream

I need to read a cd / dvd drive in raw mode using java. I know how to do so (using unc path like \.\E:\ ), and I can read some data. But if I want to skip a large amount of data it failed because of file buffering and alignment, as specified by Microsoft here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering

My sector size is 2048 bytes, if I read 2048 bytes or if I skip a multiple of 2048 bytes it works.
I am using a buffered input stream reader of 8192 bytes, and it is indeed a multiple of 2048.

But if I need to skip a non multiple number of bytes, the next read will fail.

Is there an input stream that will always issue a read of 2048 bytes to the underlying file ?

Comment: Why don't you use the `InputStream#readNBytes` method or the `skip` method to skip a multiple of 2048?

Comment: That works, but in case I need to access at a position that is not a multiple of 2048 I would need to read a block of 2048 then fetch the data I need by computing an offset in the array. I would like to use an input stream that would do that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java spec on how inputstreams in general, and `FileInputStream` / `Files.newInputStream` works are not specified to the level of detail that you can *guarantee* that it'll tell the underlying OS driver to read precisely 2048 bytes. In that sense your question is simply answerable with:  No, there is no input stream that will always issue a read of 2048 bytes to the underlying file.

However, in practice, calling `read(someByteArr)` on a new freshly opened unwrapped `new FileInputStream` on a resource, where `someByteArr` is precisely 2048 bytes in size, really should always do what you want, even if the specification doesn't quite guarantee this. Write code that always invokes the read (or skip) method with multiples of 2048 and exposes a further API that lets you read smaller parts of this, if you must.

Note that the linked document delves into OS-specific details to a level that java doesn't let you do (not without resorting to so-called `native` code; you don't want to go there, trust me). Java is not really the right tool for the job here.